# Socket.io Android Client not working but iOS Client Working

Tags: android, ios, objective-c, websocket, socket.io

We setup socket.io in our node.js server. We try to use Socket.io Java Client and Socket.io iOS Client. We able to connect through iOS but we cannot able to connect through Android. We don't have any clue , why Android is not connecting.

**Server Side:**

```
var socketIO = require('socket.io');
//var io =

GLOBAL._io = socketIO(httpServer);
_io.on('connection', (socket) => {
  console.log('Client connected');
  setInterval(() => _io.emit('time', new Date().toTimeString()), 1000);
socket.on('disconnect', () => console.log('Client disconnected'));
});
```

**Android Not Working**

```
public void addSocketConnection() throws URISyntaxException {

        Log.i("Socket.io","Init");

        mSocket = IO.socket("http://dev.myapp.com/parse");
        mSocket.on(Socket.EVENT_CONNECT,onConnect);
        mSocket.on("time",onTime);
        mSocket.on(Socket.EVENT_DISCONNECT,onDisconnect);
        mSocket.on(Socket.EVENT_CONNECT_ERROR, onConnectError);
        mSocket.on(Socket.EVENT_CONNECT_TIMEOUT, onConnectError);
        mSocket.connect();

        Log.i("Socket.io","Connect");
    }
    private Emitter.Listener onTime = new Emitter.Listener() {
        @Override
        public void call(Object... args) {

            Log.i("Socket.io","OnTime");

        }
    };

    private Emitter.Listener onConnect = new Emitter.Listener() {
        @Override
        public void call(Object... args) {

            Log.i("Socket.io","OnConnect");

        }
    };

    private Emitter.Listener onDisconnect = new Emitter.Listener() {
        @Override
        public void call(Object... args) {

            Log.i("Socket.io","DisConnect");

        }
    };
```

**iOS Working**

```
NSURL* url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:@"http://dev.myapp.com/parse"];
SocketIOClient* socket = [[SocketIOClient alloc] initWithSocketURL:url options:@{@"log": @YES, @"forcePolling": @YES}];

[socket on:@"connect" callback:^(NSArray* data, SocketAckEmitter* ack) {
    NSLog(@"socket connected");
}];
[socket onAny:^(SocketAnyEvent *event) {
    NSLog(@"On any event :%@",event.event);

}];

[socket on:@"time" callback:^(NSArray* data, SocketAckEmitter* ack) {
    NSLog(@"Time %@",data[0]);
}];

[socket connect];
```

Comment: have you tried to set  
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
into androidManifest.xml file?

Comment: OP found a solution and posted it in [this github issue](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client-java/issues/327#issuecomment-232854670).

Comment: Yes, I forgot to update at StackOverflow. Just added the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed and updated in github and forgot to update here.[github issue link](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client-java/issues/327#issuecomment-232854670)

A little bit confusion but fixed to work on both.

We have parse server URL : "http://dev.myapp.com/parse"
Our Node URL: "http://dev.myapp.com/"

By mistake we point to URL "http://dev.myapp.com/parse" for iOS, it is working.
So we point to the same URL for Android , it is not working.

Then we changed both urls to "http://dev.myapp.com", now working on both iOS and Android.

Note:
We have no clue why iOS is working for "http://dev.myapp.com/parse"